# Checking value of multiple columns in a same value set

Tags: sql, database, join, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to find an efficient way to optimize the performance of query. Can you please suggest me any different ways?

Currently I run a query like

```
SELECT  a.col1, b.colX
    FROM TableA a
    INNER JOIN TableB b
    ON a.a1Key=b.b1Key
    WHERE
       a.col2 in (select test from TableC)
    OR a.col3 in (select test from TableC)
    OR a.col4 in (select test from TableC)
    OR a.col5 in (select test from TableC)
    OR a.col6 in (select test from TableC)
    OR a.col7 in (select test from TableC)
    OR a.col8 in (select test from TableC)
```

This is slow right now.
I want to improve following part of query.

```
   a.col2 in (select test from TableC)
OR a.col3 in (select test from TableC)
OR a.col4 in (select test from TableC)
OR a.col5 in (select test from TableC)
OR a.col6 in (select test from TableC)
OR a.col7 in (select test from TableC)
OR a.col8 in (select test from TableC)`
```

Answer (score 1):

Include another `JOIN` with `TableC` like

```
SELECT  a.col1, b.colX
    FROM TableA a
    INNER JOIN TableB b
    ON a.a1Key=b.b1Key
    JOIN TableC c 
    ON c.test IN (a.col2, a.col3, a.col4, a.col5, a.col6, a.col7, a.col8);
```